# Ask NSSlider if the user still has the mouse button pressed? (swift)

Tags: cocoa, swift2, xcode7, nsslider

Hi I'm implementing a subclass of NSSlider and NSSliderCell in swift, I would like to check/retrieve the _scFlags.isPressed property from NSSliderCell, I found that there is a 'hack' in Objective-C to do it when calling from another class (which is not really needed if you subclass NSSlider in Objective-C):

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/54913-nsslider.html

However, in swift, when I search in the API (AppKit -> NSSliderCell), I can find a struct which I suppose is the one I need, and nothing else but the init() inside:

```
public struct __sliderCellFlags {
    public init()
}
```

and I can't even call it from the subclass. All these show as error:

```
self.__sliderCellFlags 
self._scFlags
super.__sliderCellFlags
super._scFlags
```

Am I missing something? Is there a different way to call these properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Objective-C to implement a category on `NSSliderCell` which has a property to access the struct data and use the property from Swift.

#### NSSlider+FlagsAccessor.h

```
@interface NSSlider (FlagsAccessor)

@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isPressed;

@end
```

#### NSSlider+FlagsAccessor.m

```
#import "NSSlider+FlagsAccessor.h"

@interface NSSliderCell (FlagsAccessor)

@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isPressed;

@end

@implementation NSSlider (FlagsAccessor)

- (BOOL)isPressed
{
    NSSliderCell *cell = self.cell;

    return cell.isPressed;
}

@end

@implementation NSSliderCell (FlagsAccessor)

- (BOOL)isPressed
{
    return self->_scFlags.isPressed == 1;
}

@end
```

Then to use It from Swift just call `self.isPressed`. [Here's a sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/452482/stackoverflow/Slider%20Flags.zip).

Don't forget to import your category header in your bridging header (Xcode will prompt you to create a bridging header when you add Objective-C code to a Swift project).

Comment: This is great, It will work for me as a good workaround until they do something about it in the swift API, thanks! One last question. If I was to add an IBOutlet in your sample project for the @IBOutlet weak var sliderCell: NSSliderCell! and one action to access its .isPressed property like: sliderCell.isPressed what should I add to the objective-C class to allow this? at the moment it can't be done, I also can't do slider.cell.isPressed

Comment: It's actually weird, I see like you shouldn't do anything at it should just pick it up... when I see the error I right click on the isPressed property and jump to definition, it does ask me to choose the right place from the options, could there be a bug in Xcode?

Comment: Why do you need `slider.cell.isPressed`? Just use `slider.isPressed` (which is behind the scenes just calling `self.cell.isPressed`, look at the implementation).